# How to replace a character at the end of a string/file?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove a rogue comma at the end of my file when formatting with PowerShell. The file in question contains the user's city, region, and country.

**Example:**

```
San Diego, California, US,
```

**But I want it to be:**

```
San Diego, California, US
```

How can I remove this last ', ' at the end using `-replace`?
My code doesn't work below:

```
(Get-Content file.txt) | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace ', ', ''
} | Set-Content file.txt
```

I just need a way of detecting that last ', ' that appears in my file without removing every comma that exists in the file.

Comment: Quizzed - If one of the answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903884/is-there-a-way-with-regex-to-grab-the-first-word-and-replace-a-quoted-section) resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 4):

You need to anchor your expression at the end of the string. In regular expressions that is done with a `$` character. Add a `\s*` if you want to ignore trailing whitespace after that last comma:

```
$_ -replace ',\s*$'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also simply use the `LastIndexOf` function of the `String` class combined with a `Substring`.

```
$test = "San Diego, California, US, "
Write-Host $test.Substring(0, $test.LastIndexOf(','))
```

output: `San Diego, California, US`

Pretty self explaining --> You select from the start of the string until the last index of your specified char or string.

This is, assuming you always have your rogue comma at the end of the string, otherwise it will trim the text after a "good" comma.

Comment: I know its not actuall answer on the question about regex, but searching the internet, it helped me to solve my problem . Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

while the regex solution is likely faster than string methods, you *can* use string methods to do the job. [*grin*]

- use `.Trim()` to remove any leading or trailing whitespace
- use `.TrimEnd(',')` to remove any trailing comma chars

like this ...

```
'San Diego, California, US, '.Trim().TrimEnd(',')
```

output = `San Diego, California, US`