# Is there a way with Regex to grab the first word and replace a quoted section?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to replace **ACACIA_BOAT** (just a placeholder when copying things) with the first word, that being the variable name.

```
SCAFFOLDING = new ItemBuilder(Material.valueOf("ACACIA_BOAT")).build();
SEAGRASS = new ItemBuilder(Material.valueOf("ACACIA_BOAT")).build();
SKULL_BANNER_PATTERN = new ItemBuilder(Material.valueOf("ACACIA_BOAT")).build();

// into this

SCAFFOLDING = new ItemBuilder(Material.valueOf("SCAFFOLDING")).build();
SEAGRASS = new ItemBuilder(Material.valueOf("SEAGRASS")).build();
SKULL_BANNER_PATTERN = new ItemBuilder(Material.valueOf("SKULL_BANNER_PATTERN")).build();
```

Just an example. There's thousands of entries across classes.

Any way to simplify this process with Regex?

I'm using IntelliJ if that helps.

Comment: `sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)"ACACIA_BOAT"/\1 \2"\1"/' ` if you're using an OS with the `sed` command.

Answer (score 4):

**How to Find and replace text using regular expressions in Intellij in project**

In this case Intellij 2020.2 was used.

You will find the replacement tool under menu:

**Edit/Find/'Replace in Path...'**

or go shortcut:

**Ctrl+Shift+R**

**In search window type:**

```
(\w+) = new ItemBuilder\(Material\.valueOf\(\\"ACACIA_BOAT\\"
```

**In replacement window type:**

```
$1 = new ItemBuilder\(Material\.valueOf\(\\"$1\\"
```

**Make sure the following is selected:**

- **Match case 'Aa'**  - found on the right hand side of "search window" (It is lit with blue color when it is activated)
- **Regex '.*'** - found on the right hand side of "search window" (It is lit with blue color when it is activated)
- **'In Project'** - found on the left hand side just under the "replacement window"

After settings click button 'Replace All' to execute request.

Below is a picture of the "tool", using requested regex:

[image]

Read more about Intellij's "Find and replace with regex" at:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html