# Regex workaround infinite repetition inside lookbehind

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match the text `value_to_match` when preceeded by a line `"attribute": "type"` and preceeded (at some point) by a `"marketTypeId": 123456789` in Intellij regex search.

In the following text the search should match `value_to_match` only.

```
    {
      "marketTypeId": 123456789,
      "description": "Market description",
      "periodType": "MATCH",
      "periodInstance": 1,
      "feedMappingData": [
        {
          "outcomeIdFeedcodeMap": {
            "2": "123456789001",
            "1": "123456789002"
          },
          "conditions": [
            {
              "element": "Market",
              "attribute": "type",
              "condition": "EQUALS",
              "value": "value_to_match"
            },
            {
              "element": "Market",
              "attribute": "traded_pre_match",
              "condition": "EQUALS",
              "value": "true"
            }
          ]
        },
    {
      "marketTypeId": 12121212,
      "description": "Market description",
      "periodType": "MATCH",
      "periodInstance": 1,
      "feedMappingData": [
        {
          "outcomeIdFeedcodeMap": {
            "2": "12121212001",
            "1": "12121212002"
          },
          "conditions": [
            {
              "element": "Market",
              "attribute": "type",
              "condition": "EQUALS",
              "value": "value_NOT_to_match"
            },
            {
              "element": "Market",
              "attribute": "traded_pre_match",
              "condition": "EQUALS",
              "value": "true"
            }
          ]
        },
```

I've been trying to use lookbehind with the conditions but it seems Intellij regex search does not support infinite repetition inside lookbehind.
Is there any workaround for situations like this?

Comment: (?<=marketTypeId":\s?)(?:123456789)(?=,\n)(?:(?s).*?"attribute":\s?"type",.*?"value":\s?")(.*)(?=") matches the whole block from the markeTypeId to the value I want to match and the value_to_match is captured in a group... but it does not help...

Comment: Isn't that JSON? Why don't you use a JSON parser?

Comment: my idea is not to use it in the code, quite often i need to retrieve some strings from huge json files and i search in IntelliJ for convenience. using regex search seems the most pratical way to retrieve a bunch of those matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Intellij and positive lookbehind**

The regex used in Intellij:

```
(?s)(?<="marketTypeId":\s123456789,.{1,500}"attribute":\s"type",.{1,100}"value":\s")value_to_match(?=")
```

**Note:**

> Dotall mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?s)

Read more about this flag expression and regex lookarounds in reference:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Used Intellij version 2020.2

Picture of Intellij and match:

[image]

More can be read about Intellij and matching here:

[Is there a way with Regex to grab the first word and replace a quoted section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903884/is-there-a-way-with-regex-to-grab-the-first-word-and-replace-a-quoted-section/63435607#63435607)

Comment: Happy to hear :)